# how to rewrite image url using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter

Tags: image, url-rewriting

Can anyone say how to rewrite image url using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter?

In the page faqs.aspx, there is a image. The image is retrieved from database and rendered in contentimage.aspx.
Image src is http://localhost/MySite/SG/FAQs/images/en/bridge_singapore.jpg.
I have to rewirte as http://localhost/MySite/ContentImage.aspx?id=SG&type=FAQs&lang=en&filename=bridge_singapore.jpg.

Currently, I write as follows and it doesn't work at all.

```
<rewrite url="~/(.+)/faqs/images/(.+)/(.+).jpg" to="~/contentimage.aspx?id=$1&amp;type=faqs&amp;lang=$2&amp;filename=$3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

At last, I know my problem. :) ...
It is due to my IIS setting.
In the Handler Mappings, it only allows .aspx extension to be handled
by aspnet_isapi.dll.  So, I added custom handlers for .jpg extension
to be handled by aspnet_isapi.dll. 
Now, it works fine.  :)